# How to ssh through a proxy server, sometimes

Tags: ssh, proxy

On my work laptop, if I need to SSH to a non-work machine, I need to go through a proxy server, but only when I'm on the work network (either in the office or on the VPN). I do this by setting a ProxyCommand line in my SSH config file. When I'm not in the office or on the WAN, though, I don't want to use the proxy. Is there an easy way to automate the decision to use or not use the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

[Answer compliments of [kasperd](https://serverfault.com/users/214507/kasperd%20%22kasperd) over on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/889410/21814).]

In your .ssh/config use the `Match` keyword to create a conditional section.

The `Match` keyword takes different arguments, one of them is `exec` which will allow you to run an external command and use the return value of that command to decide whether this section applies or not.

You can use that to run a script that inspects whatever network settings you can use to tell the difference between the different networks. The script needs to return 0 when a `ProxyCommand` is needed and any non-zero value when a `ProxyCommand` is not needed.

Here is an example of what the config could look like:

```
Match host external-host.example.com exec /home/joe/bin/need-proxy
  ProxyCommand /home/joe/bin/proxy-script %h %p
```